# How to access or get current image in BMP from Axis network camera?

Tags: c#, ip-camera

I am facing a problem regarding accessing the frame from the IP camera.
I am using Axis M1013 camera, and I want to perform various operations like color detection and object detection.
I am able to call the camera, but I don't know how to get current image so I can perform other operations on it.

Here is my code:

```
private void Play_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //viewIPCamera();
    AMC1.MediaURL = "169.254.103.123//axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi";;
    AMC1.MediaUsername = "root";
    AMC1.MediaPassword = "password";
    AMC1.MediaType = "mjpeg";
    AMC1.Play();
```

So how can I get the current image from a network camera?

Answer (score 0):

Axis cameras use the ONVIF standard, maybe try something like this.

```
using Ozeki.Media.IPCamera;
using Ozeki.Media.MediaHandlers.Video;
using Ozeki.Media.Video.Controls;
using Ozeki.Media.MediaHandlers;


public partial class Snapshot {

    private SnapshotHandler _snapshotHandler;

    private void CreateSnapShot(string path) {
                var date = DateTime.Now.Year + "y-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "m-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "d-" +
                           DateTime.Now.Hour + "h-" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "m-" + DateTime.Now.Second + "s";
                string currentpath;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                    currentpath = date + ".jpg";
                else
                    currentpath = path + "\\" + date + ".jpg";

                var snapShotImage = _snapshotHandler.TakeSnapshot().ToImage();
                snapShotImage.Save(currentpath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

}

This link can get you started:

[How to create ONVIF Ip camera snapshot](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/829261/How-to-create-ONVIF-IP-camera-snapshot-as-a-JPG-im)

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @max0118 Check my post, I have included some sample code for a Ozeki camera, maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the Axis SDK this may help.

```
object myBuffer;
int myBufferSize;
AMC1.GetCurrentImage(0, out myBuffer, out myBufferSize) ;
byte[] returningBytes = new byte[myBufferSize];
//Add JPEG header to new byte array
returningBytes[0] =  Convert.ToByte(255);
returningBytes[1] = Convert.ToByte(216);
returningBytes[2] = Convert.ToByte(255);
returningBytes[3] = Convert.ToByte(224);
returningBytes[4] = Convert.ToByte(0);
returningBytes[5] = Convert.ToByte(16);
returningBytes[6] = Convert.ToByte(74);
returningBytes[7] = Convert.ToByte(70);
returningBytes[8] = Convert.ToByte(73);
returningBytes[9] = Convert.ToByte(70);
//Copy actual image into new byte array
Buffer.BlockCopy(myBuffer as Array, 10, returningBytes, 10, myBufferSize - 10);
```

returningBytes is now a proper bytearray and can be saved to a database or converted to a memorystream to populate a picturebox. Take note that I did use a jpeg and not bmp as the OP requested though.